# Storing and fetching data in database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

What I need the app to do is to store data in a database and let any user fetch the data. I am not sure how SQLite works but from what I know is that it is server-less. With the database being serverless, how do multiple users, other users, access the same data if it is not stored on a server?

Comment: SQLite is for local data storage. You'll need a server if you want to share data. Either cloud-based or self-hosted. There is plenty information out there for someone willing to put in the effort to search it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is installed on all android systems, and any app which wishes to create and use a database may do so. This however, is only stored locally on the device.

If you wish to share and synchronize data across multiple devices, that is a different issue all to itself. Indeed it will very likely involve a central server somewhere along the line.

Perhaps start your reading at d.android.com

Answer (score 2):

look for backend and a service - parse.com or similar.